# how to bake a roughness map with different intensity reflections

Tags: materials, texture-painting, texture-baking

I color my object with two colors, the first color uses metal elements, then for the second color I make it with metal elements as well but for the second material I make it by drawing in a texture paint, so the two colors overlap (the first color is below and the second color is above)  then what I wanted to ask, how do I bake the two materials with different reflex intensities? ( to lowpoly object)

[image: black is first color and the white is secondary color]

Answer (score 0):

Use a Mix Shader node to combine your two different materials then use a black and white mask to tell that material what part is what, if you don't want to make a new texture you might be able to get away with doing a color ramp.
[image]